# How to store image into MySQL database using Spring Boot and ReactJS

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

file: Employee.java

```
package net.employee_crud.springboot.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private String emailId;
    
    @Column(name = "department_name")
    private String department;
    
    public Employee() {
        
    }
    
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String emailId, String department) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.department = department;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }
    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

EmployeeController.java

```
package net.employee_crud.springboot.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import net.employee_crud.springboot.exception.ResourceNotFounudException;
import net.employee_crud.springboot.model.Employee;
import net.employee_crud.springboot.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class EmployeeController {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    //get all employees api
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
                
    }
    
    //Create employee rest api
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
    
    //get employee by id rest api
    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeebyId(@PathVariable Long id) {
        
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new ResourceNotFounudException("Employee Not exist with id: " + id));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employee);
    }
    
    //Update employee rest api
    @PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@PathVariable Long id,@RequestBody Employee employee_details){
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new ResourceNotFounudException("Employee Not exist with id: " + id));
        
        employee.setFirstName(employee_details.getFirstName());
        employee.setLastName(employee_details.getLastName());
        employee.setEmailId(employee_details.getEmailId());
        employee.setDepartment(employee_details.getDepartment());
        
        Employee updated_Employee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updated_Employee);
    }
    
    //Delete Employee rest api
    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Boolean>>deleteEmployee(@PathVariable long id){
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new ResourceNotFounudException("Employee Not exist with id: " + id));
        
        employeeRepository.delete(employee);
        Map<String,Boolean> ans = new HashMap<>();
        ans.put("deleted",Boolean.TRUE);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ans);
    }
    
}
```

I have 4 columns in Employee table, firstName, lastName, emailId, department_name. Now i want to add 1 more column which will store employee_profile photo. How can i store image in database. I don't want to store image as BLOB. If that is not possible to do without storing it as BLOB, then provide me that solution.

Comment: It's possible to store Images in MySQL without using BLOB but that is not recommended as it can cause some issues while processing high-quality (Big-size) images, I would like to know why you don't want to go for BLOB or any AWS or Azure services like S3 or Azure Blob as you can store your images there and keep the path on your MySQL database it would be more convinenitnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We can solve this with below steps with mysql longtext not BLOB :**

- alter query to add new filed to store employee photo

> alter table employees add employee_profile_photo longtext null;

- update your `Employee` entity for new field `employeeProfilePhoto`

  ```
  @Column(name = "employee_profile_photo")
  private String employeeProfilePhoto;
  ```
- update controller method

```
@PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee, @RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams, HttpServletRequest request) {

        MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        MultipartFile employeeProfilePhotoObj = multipartRequest.getFile("employeeProfilePhoto");

        String employeeProfilePhoto =  getImageString(employeeProfilePhotoObj);
        employeeProfilePhoto.setEmployeeProfilePhoto(employeeProfilePhoto);

        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
```

- add below method to for `MultipartFile` to `Base64` string conversion

```
 public String getImageString(MultipartFile multipartFile) {

        try {
            byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray( multipartFile.getInputStream());
            return  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception during image read", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

- display photo to react

```
const Photo = ({employeeObj}) => {
    let imageData = employeeObj.employeeProfilePhoto;
    return (
        < >
            {imageData && <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${imageData}`} alt="Photo" />}
        </>  
    );
};

export default Photo;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store the image directly as a BLOB (Binary Large Object) in the database, an alternative approach is to store the images on the server (or a cloud storage service) and save the file path or URL in the database. This way, you store the metadata about the image in the database, and the actual image is stored as a file.

Here are the steps to modify your `Employee` entity and `EmployeeController` to support image storage:

#### 1. Modify `Employee` Entity:

Add a new field to store the file path or URL for the employee profile photo:

```java
// Import necessary libraries

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    // Existing fields...

    @Column(name = "profile_photo_path") // Change the column name as needed
    private String profilePhotoPath;

    // Constructors, getters, setters...
}
```

#### 2. Modify `EmployeeController`:

Adjust the controller to handle image uploads and save the file path to the database.

```java
// Import necessary libraries

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class EmployeeController {

    // Existing code...

    // Create employee with profile photo rest api
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        // Assuming you have a method to handle file upload and return the file path
        String profilePhotoPath = handleProfilePhotoUpload(employee.getProfilePhoto());

        // Set the profile photo path in the employee object
        employee.setProfilePhotoPath(profilePhotoPath);

        // Save the employee object with the profile photo path
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    // Existing code...

    // Method to handle profile photo upload (You need to implement this)
    private String handleProfilePhotoUpload(MultipartFile profilePhoto) {
        // Implement the logic to handle file upload
        // Save the file to a server or a cloud storage service
        // Return the file path or URL
        return "path/to/profile/photo.jpg"; // Replace with the actual path or URL
    }
}
```

#### 3. Frontend Integration:

Modify your frontend to include the logic for uploading profile photos. When creating or updating an employee, you will need to send the image file along with other employee details to the server.

Ensure that you have a mechanism to handle file uploads on the frontend and send the file data to the corresponding endpoint on the server.

By following this approach, you can store image files externally while keeping only the file path or URL in the database. This is a common practice in many applications to efficiently manage image storage.